# How search text contain single quotes with linq.js?

Tags: linq.js

I using linq.js at: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/linq.js/2.2.0.2/linq.js
 This is sample data to test:

```
var list = [{ a: "50", b: 4, c: 1 },
                    { a: "60", b: 3, c: 7 },
                    { a: "50'60", b: 3, c: 3 }];
var val = "50'60";
var res = Enumerable.From(list).Where("$.a=='" + val +"'").ToArray();
```

I had try replace `1 single quotes` => `2 single quotes`, but it still not working.

How search text contain single quotes with linq.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my solution :

```
        var list = [
                    { a: "50", b: 4, c: 1 },
                    { a: "60", b: 3, c: 7 },
                    { a: "50'60", b: 3, c: 3 }];
                var val = "50'60";
                val=val.replace(/'/g,"*");
                var res = Enumerable.From(list).Where("($.a).replace(\"'\",\"*\")=='" + val +"'").ToArray();
```